# Google API is showing an old address for a business

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I was trying to create a direct link to a Google business review.  I went to the Google Place ID and found the company, but it's showing both the old (at the top) and current address (in the box with the ID code)
[I have a screenshot that shows the Google Place ID page with the old address and new address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMCdO.png)

How can I update the information at the top so that both addresses are the same, current listing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is happening in **[Google Maps](https://www.google.com)** as well. I would like to suggest in **[Google Maps](https://www.google.com)**, look for the **Menu Icon** (located at the top left part of the page) and click **"Send feedback"**. In there, you can either choose **"Suggest an edit"** or **"Other feedback"**. Just provide clear details on how to reproduce your concern.

On the other hand, if you are the owner of this business, you can manage or edit locations in your **[Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/)**. Just be informed that it may take some time for your edits to take effect.

Hope this helps you!